# How to remove Center Crop from Circular ImageView in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, uiimageview

I am using "https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView" library for Circular ImageView but the problem is this it is Center Crop by default. I want to change it scale type. How can I?

Code:

```
   <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dp80"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp80"
                    android:padding="@dimen/dp2"
                    android:src="@drawable/blank_profile" />
```

Comment: What `scaleType` do you want?

Comment: ultimatly its an imageview did u try to use android:scaleType="type of scale"

Comment: if you use retrofit it has an option for circleimage

Comment: It's not possible with this library. Only `CENTER_CROP` is supported. Please refer here: https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView/issues/116

Comment: I don't want it not to center crop @tahsinRupam

Answer (score 1):

You can't, according to the library.

> The ScaleType is always CENTER_CROP and you'll get an exception if you try to change it. This is (currently) by design as it's perfectly fine for profile images.

[CircleImageView Limitations](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView#limitations)

You can always try to ovverride this behaviour by forking the library and editing the source code in order to fit your needs. But, the library in it's current state won't allow it.